# Call Json function in controller extension method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing `Controller` extension method which is returning `JsonResult`.
Something like this:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static JsonResult AjaxRedirect(this Controller cntrl, string action, object routeValues)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there a way to use `protected internal JsonResult Json(object data);` function inside this extension method? That function can be used inside any controller method, but I don't know how to use it inside this extension method...
And if not, what is the best replacement for it?

Comment: Actually it seems that extension methods cant be written for Controller...

Comment: why you can't? You can. Where if your  `protected internal JsonResult Json(object data);` located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `BaseController` for your Controllers which inherits from `Controller` then wrap `Json` function into another public function for example `JsonPublic()` and then make an extension method for `BaseController`

```
   public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult JsonPublic(object data)
        {
            return Json(data);
        }
    }


    public static class ControllerExtensions
    {
        public static JsonResult AjaxRedirect(this BaseController cntrl, string action, object routeValues)
        {
            cntrl.JsonPublic() // accessible
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did this and it can access JsonPublic, but the problem is I dont see AjaxRedirect method in MyController which now extends BaseController. I tried with AjaxRedirect, this.AjaxRedirect, base.AjaxRedirect and it doesnt see it. I imported the correct namespace. Like it doesnt allow me to create extension method for controller.